# Grouping an outcome in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm doing a simple MySQL Query and would like to use GROUP to give me a set of results for all of my locations rather than having to run the query uncommenting the various lines on each occasion. I'm confused about whether or not to use GROUP in the SELECT or WHERE clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
Users AS u
-- Northern Ireland
WHERE u.postcode_area IN ('BT')
-- WALES
-- WHERE u.postcode_area IN ('CF','CH','GL')
-- Scotland
-- WHERE u.postcode_area IN ('AB','DD','DG','EH','FK')
```

So as an outcome I'd like to see

- Northern Ireland | 25678
- Wales            | 34543
- Scotland         | 4567

Comment: Well, you certainly have tables for relations between 'BT' and 'Northern Ireland' and 'CF', 'CH', 'GL' and 'Wales', don't you ? So can you show that part of your structure ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. There are no relational tables here, Northern Ireland, Wales and Scotland are simply labels. Thanks

Comment: I would still be a good idea to a that relational table. It will keep your query maintainable and you never know when you still might need the same data somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN u.postcode_area IN ('BT') THEN 'Northern Ireland'
        WHEN u.postcode_area IN ('CF','CH','GL') THEN 'WALES'
        WHEN u.postcode_area IN ('AB','DD','DG','EH','FK') THEN 'Scotland'
        ELSE 'other') AS country,
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    Users AS u
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much, just missing the END off the CASE. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try it like this:

```
select 
  if(u.postcode_area in ('BT'), 'Northern Ireland', 
    if(u.postcode_area in ('CF','CH','GL'), 'Wales', 
      if(u.postcode_area in ('AB','DD','DG','EH','FK'), 'Scotland', 
        'Unknown'
      )
    )
  ) as label
  , count(*)
from Users as u
group by label
```

**edit:**

By the way, it would be neater to have a table containing postcode_area linked to label.

Northern Ireland | BT
Wales | CF
Wales | CH
Wales | GL
Scotland | AB
Scotland | DD
Scotland | DG
Scotland | EH
Scotland | FK

then your query would be:

```
select
  pl.label,
  count(*) as count
from
  Users as u
  inner join containing postcode_area_label as pl
    on u.postcode_area = pl.postcode_area
group by
  pl.label
```

Comment: xdazz's Case looks neater than the nested if's I use. For the rest it's the same

Comment: Thanks, our database is set up as you suggest. I just needed  an example for the GROUP clause. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This will give all three results at the same time:

```
SELECT ireland.ireland_count, wales.wales_count, scotland.scotland_count FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) as ireland_count FROM Users WHERE postcode_area IN ('BT')) as ireland
JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) as wales_count FROM Users WHERE postcode_area IN ('CF','CH','GL')) as wales
JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) as scotland_count FROM Users WHERE postcode_area IN ('AB','DD','DG','EH','FK')) as scotland;
```

The output will be like:

```
ireland_count   |   wales_count    |   scotland_count
25678           |   34543          |   4567
```